# Can I use Stripe to buy in app currency in my Android App?

Tags: android, flutter, stripe-payments, in-app-purchase, google-play-console

Can I use Stripe to buy In App Currency in my android app. My app is released on play store.

Comment: No. Play policies strictly says to use Google Play's Billing. There are exceptions for purchase of physical goods though.